# dict AttributeError only when accessing via dot operator

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am creating a dict like this:

```
request = {"method": "get"}
```

and when I try to list the attributes with

```
print list(request.keys())
```

I get what I'd expect:

```
['method']
```

And I can access the `method` attribute with

```
print request['method']
```

and I get what I'd expect:

```
get
```

But if I try to

```
print request.method
```

I get an error

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'

Why am I getting an error with a `.` but not when I use square brackets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two operations translate into different method calls:

- `request['method']` translates into [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)
- `request.method` translates into [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

Dictionary's API in python works through "subscript-able interface". Meaning, its items are expected to be accessed through the `get` method or through `[]` index.

The reason that one works and the other fails is that operations are not equivalent. The reason that only the `get` and `[]` works are due to the implementation in python.

Simulating access by member can be easily done by overriding [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

request = AttrDict({'method': 'get'})
method = request.method  # 'get'
```

Comment: If `.` translates to `__getattribute__`, I'm unclear why overriding `__getattr__` will work?

Comment: I may have oversimplified it. `__getattribute__` is called before accessing any attribute of an object, such as the `get` function or `keys` function. `__getattr__` on the other hand, is called only when the requested attribute is missing. In the example, `__getattr__` means that it won't hide built-in functions of `dict`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The dot notation is usually used to get an attribute of an object. For example:

```
class Dog:    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

d = Dog(name = 'Fuffy')

print d.name # 'Fuffy'
```

When you want get an item from a dictionary by its `key`, you have to use the notation `dict['key']` or, probably less common, also:

```
dict.get(key, default=None)
```

where default (which defaults to `None`) is the value to be returned if key does not exist. For example

```
request = {"method": "get"}
print request.get('method','foo') # get
print request.get('bar','foo') # foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you simply cannot get values from dictionaries by using keys that way (`dict.key` is *not* the same as `dict["key"]` - it invokes a different method when used, as seen in @Elisha's answer).

`"method"` is not an attribute, it is a **key** referring to the **value** `"get"`. The only valid ways to get a value from a dictionary, given a key, in your case are `request["method"]` and `request.get("method", "defaultmethod")`.

Hope this helped!