# Generate jwcrypto JWK from azure python sdk JWK

Tags: python, azure, jwt, azure-keyvault, jwk

I'm using [azure-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) to get a key from an Azure Key Vault. This returns a *KeyBundle*, which has a *key* attribute of type `azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.json_web_key_py3.JsonWebKey`

For a different part of my code, I need to make a signed token from a [jwcrypto](https://github.com/latchset/jwcrypto) JWK. The `JWT.make_signed_token` method takes a JsonWebKey. The JsonWebKey returned from Azure is (I think) effectively the same class, defined in a different package.

Is there a way to make the Azure JWK into a jwcrypto JWK? I assume it would be possible to transpose all attributes one by one, but was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Edit: Forgot to include versions...

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.5
- jwcrypto 0.6.0
- azure-keyvault 1.1.0 and azure-mgmt-keyvault 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to convert an Azure JWK object to a `jwcrypto` JWK object is as the code below.

```
import jwcrypto.jwk as jwk

azureJwkObj = .... # your Azure JWK object
azureJwkDict = azureJwkObj.__dict__

jwcryptoJwkObject = jwk.JWK(**azureJwkDict)
```

Also the same below.

```
jwcryptoJwkObject = jwk.JWK().import_key(**azureJwkDict)
```

<s>I think there is a function `import_key` of `jwcrypto.jwk.JWK` required a `dict` as parameter to generate a `jwcrypto` JWK object after I reviewed the source code of Azure KeyVault SDK and `jwcrypto` for Python.</s>

According to the source code [`json_web_key_py3.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-keyvault/azure/keyvault/v7_0/models/json_web_key_py3.py) of Azure KeyVault SDK and [`jwk.py`](https://github.com/latchset/jwcrypto/blob/master/jwcrypto/jwk.py) of `jwcrypto`, I tried to generate a `jwcrypto` JWK object to see its structure via the code below.

```
from jwcrypto import jwk
key = jwk.JWK.generate(kty='oct', size=256)
print(key.__dict__)
# The output is {'_params': {'kty': 'oct'}, '_key': {'k': 'HJUk1CeudZ2Tur0fzHnOi-1U9UjxaUjClRW8TvqFakI'}, '_unknown': {}}
```

Then, I tried to use the code below to convert an Azure JWK object to a dictory required by `jwcrypto.jwk.JWK.import_key` to create a `jwcrypto` JWK object via `import_key` function.

```
import jwcrypto.jwk as jwk

azureJwkObj = .... # your Azure JWK object
azureJwkDict = azureJwkObj.__dict__

_params = {k: v for k, v in azureJwkDict.items() if k in jwk.JWKParamsRegistry.keys()}
kty = _params.get('kty', None)
_key = {k: v for k, v in azureJwkDict.items() if k in jwk.JWKValuesRegistry[kty].keys()}

args = {'_params': _params, '_key': _key, '_unknown': {}}

jwcryptoJwkObject = jwk.JWK.import_key(args)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) It all seems fine until I run the `import_key` function. I get an AttributeError:
`File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwk.py", line 365, in import_key

    kty = self._params.get('kty', None)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_params'`

Comment: @EllaP I don't familiar with Python 3 inside ArcGIS. Could you post more information about this Python of ArcGIS, such as Python version in details? Also, you can post your code and other useful thing to help me fix this issue. Tks.

Comment: It's just a standard python 3.6.5 distribution that comes as part of the ArcGIS software. I used the azure package like this `azureJwkObj = azureKeyVaultClient.get_key(vault_url, key_name, key_version).key` and copied your code afterwards. I get _args_ to be a dictionary of dictionaries, is that what type it should be?

Comment: @EllaP Per my experience, the issue was not caused by code, but others of your Python scripts or env. Please check your Python environment, such as `import sys; print(sys.path)` to check whether there is a same name script file to cause name conflict issue with `jwcrypto` installed by yourself via `pip install jwcrypto`, or other reason you can search in Google or Bing to find out.

Comment: I tried creating some example dictionaries and accessing keys using dot notation but this seems to produce an AttributeError. I've had a look at some SO questions about this (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237990/dict-attributeerror-only-when-accessing-via-dot-operator) ) and will look into it more. The source code for jwk seems to use dot notation and I don't really want to mess about with it.

Comment: @EllaP Sorry, it's my code fault. I have update my post after I tried to review `jwcrypto` Github repo and test my code.

Comment: Using the revised code throws `jwcrypto.jwk.InvalidJWKValue: "d" is not Base64urlUInt encoded` errors but that's because a few of the parameters of my key are empty. I needed to retrieve a private key from the vault (not possible and outside the scope of this question), but your solution would have probably worked if I was trying to get a public key. Thank you for the efforts!